# UITableView resets to start position before the user has released it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an app with an `UITableView` and its data gets updated regularly. If the data receives new element, the table view is reloaded. Let’s say the table view has place for 10 visible cells, but data for only 2 of them. The user has scrolled in either direction and not released the table view from touch. If the user has scrolled up, they may have hidden the first cell and only the second one would be visible. Then a new element is received and reloadData is called. Instead of waiting for releasing the table view to update, the tableview gets updated right away and the `contentOffset` is reset to 0. The tableView just resets to start position while the user has scrolled and not released.

I tried similar setup in separate Xcode project and the issue does not appear there. I wonder what the difference could be.

This is some of the code:

For the `ViewController` that is the `dataSource`:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   //some other code

   DataManager.shared.onElementReceival = { [weak self] in

        guard let self = self else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }   
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DataManager.shared.data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    if let name = DataManager.shared.data[indexPath.row].name {
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Unnamed"
    }

    return cell
}
```

From the DataManager

```
func didReceive(_ element: Element) {

    data.append(element)
    onElementReceival()

}
```

Comment: Do no reload entire tableView. Just reload rows you edit or insert or delete or move them if needed.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I tried like this also, but it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload only cell using:

```
tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([IndexPath(forRow: Yourarray.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

In your example:

```
let onElementReceival:(IndexPath) -> Void = { [weak self] inx in      
      guard let self = self else { return }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
           tablview.beginUpdates()
           tablview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(at: [inx], with: .automatic)
           tablview.endUpdates()
      }
}
```

From DataManager

```
func didReceive(_ element: Element) {

    data.append(element)
    onElementReceival(IndexPath(row:data.count, section: 0))

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion but it crashes the app. I guess `reloadData` or `insertRows` needs to be called for a new element before trying to reload its row

Comment: Yes, You can try this. But need to use ```insertRows```  between ```tableview.beginUpdates()``` and ```tableview.endUpdates()```

Comment: I checked and the issue remains - the offset is still reset on the update.

Comment: Just one cell at a time